# How to change files in External libraries folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I was busy adding the simple_form and mail_form gem to my rails 4.2.6 application and i wasn't satisfied with the design. The only place i can think of to change this design at the moment is in the external libraries folder. But is it even possible to change those files successfully or does it not affect my application at all. And if it DOES help how do you save changes made in the external libraries, cause it doesn't show directly in the views on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change of a gem will only be reflected upon restarting your application (via `rails s`).

As for modifications to available gems, I would fork them, modify and then specify the source repository in the `Gemfile` using the [:git](http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html) option.